# Why do I get "Error 100: Can only call this method on valid test users for your app"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I added a new new application and am trying to use Open Graph to add an action to a user's timeline. I've setup the actions according to the tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) but every time I try to add to the timeline i get this error:

"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app"

Sandbox mode is not and has never been enabled. If I try to use a test user the call completes successfully but never adds data to the test user's timeline.

Comment: I had an incorrect url. I was posting to /me/me/ which is what I believe was causing my problem.

Comment: ^^^^ You should post that as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an incorrect url. I was posting to /me/me/ which is what I believe was causing my problem.